# Оптимизация решения для прохода по времени

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация

Есть задача: существует n товаров, а также m купонов, i-й из которых позволяет уменьшить стоимость ровно одного предмета на d в том случае, если изначальная цена была хотя бы l рублей. Я написал решение, где сортирую массив пар относительно `di`, после чего нахожу при помощи бин поиска минимально стоящий товар, цена которого хотя бы `li` рублей, после удаляю этот элемент массива и прибавляю новую цену в ans. Видимо в удалении и кроется проблема, но я не знаю как без этого сделать так, чтобы на один и тот же товар не действовало больше одного купона.

В первой строке даны целые числа n и m (1 ≤ n, m ≤ 2⋅10^5) — количество предметов и купонов.

Во второй строке перечислены числа c (1 ≤ ci ≤ 10^9) — стоимости предметов.

В третьей строке перечислены числа l (1 ≤ li ≤ 10^9) — минимальные цены предметов для использования купонов.

В четвертой строке перечислены числа d (1 ≤ di ≤ li) — скидки после использования купонов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#define len(a) ((int)((a).size()))

using namespace std;

bool cmp(const pair<int, int>& f, const pair<int, int>& s) {
     if (f.first != s.first)
          return f.first < s.first;
     return f.second > s.second;
}

int32_t main() {
     ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
     cin.tie(nullptr);

     int n, m;
     cin >> n >> m;
     vector<int> c(n);
     vector<pair<int, int>> ld(m);
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cin >> c[i];
     for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) cin >> ld[i].first;
     for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) cin >> ld[i].second;

     stable_sort(ld.begin(), ld.end(), cmp);
     stable_sort(c.begin(), c.end());

     int i = 0, j = 0;
     while (i < n && j < m) {
          if (c[i] >= ld[j].first) {
               c[i] -= ld[j].second;
               ++j;
          }
          ++i;
     }

     long long ans = 0;
     for (auto& num : c) ans += num;
     cout << ans;

     return 0;
}
```

```
Входные данные:
10 5
9 7 1 5 2 2 5 5 7 6
7 2 7 8 2
3 2 4 1 2
```

```
Ответ:
37
```

Comment: вы постоянно копируете аргумент вектор. передавайте её ссылку `int bs(vector<int> const & a, int q)`

Comment: Текущий код не соответствует описанию.

Comment: Текущий код иногда не выбирает максимальную возможную скидку: *n = 1*, *m = 2*, *c = [5]*, *l = [1, 2]*, *d = [1, 2]*. Ваш код выберет скидку единица, хотя возможна большая скидка.

Comment: Задача выглядит сложной. Какой-то жадный алгоритм выдумать можно, но хотелось бы убедиться что он рабочий. Сортируем товары по цене, сортируем купоны по лимиту. Бежим по товарам, купоны с подходящими лимитами помещаем в приоритетную очередь по размеру скидки. Если очередь не пуста выбираем купон с максимальной скидкой. Что такое. Но решает ли оно задачу?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy то есть обрабатывая каждый товар, в очереди находится лишь элементы с подходящими лимитами, а первый из них всегда тот, у которого самая большая скидка (по приоритету)?

Comment: Да, вы все поняли правильно.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy извините, но ссылку дать не могу. Брат младший попросил помочь с отбором, а я решение придумать не смог :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отсортируем товары по цене, купоны по лимиту. Перебираем товары, купоны с подходящими лимитами помещаем в [кучу](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). Куча максимальная, упорядочена по скидке. Если для данного товара куча не пуста, выбираем из неё максимальную скидку и применяем её. Можно показать что этот жадный алгоритм набирает максимально возможную сумму скидок. Сложность *O(NlogN + (N + M)logM)*:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int m;
    std::cin >> m;

    std::vector<int> c(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { std::cin >> c[i]; }

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ld(m);
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) { std::cin >> ld[j].first; }
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) { std::cin >> ld[j].second; }

    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
    std::sort(ld.begin(), ld.end());

    std::priority_queue<int> q;
    long long s = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (auto ci : c) {
        s += ci;
        while (j < m && ld[j].first <= ci) {
            q.push(ld[j].second);
            ++j;
        }
        if (!q.empty()) {
            s -= q.top();
            q.pop();
        }
    }
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создадим очередь с приоритетом, обрабатывая каждый товар, добавляем в очередь возможные купоны по лимиту. Приоритет основан на скидке, поэтому top очереди это всегда купон с максимальной скидкой для данного товара. Спасибо @Stanislav Volodarskiy за помощь с решением!

```cpp
struct Coupon {
    int l, d;
    
    bool operator<(const Coupon& x) const {
        return d < x.d;
    }
}

int main() {
    // вводим вектор чисел c
    // вводим вектор пар ld
    // сортируем оба вектора. Вектор пар сортируем относительно границы купона

    priority_queue<Coupon> q;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         while (ld[j].first <= c[i] && j < m) {
              q.push({ld[j].first, ld[j].second});
              ++j;
         }
         if (!q.empty()) {
              c[i] -= q.top().d;
              q.pop();
         }
    }
    // ответ - сумма всех чисел массива c
}
```